# Generating .so file

Tags: c++, gcc, dependencies, dynamic-linking, .so

I have file `main.c`, I want to create `main.so`.

`main.c` depends on `libCmodel.so` file.

`main.c` looks like

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "Cmodel.h" // Must include before Amodel and Bmodel
#include "Amodel.h"
#include "Bmodel.h"

int main(){
..
return 0;
}
```

It can be observed that, `libCmodel.so` file depends on `libAmodel.so.4` and `libBmodelso.11.`
All the `"*.so"` files are present in the same directory as `main.c`

I used the following command to generate object file

```
gcc -x c++ -fPIC main.c -o main.o -c -I.
```

I see that `main.o` is generated. 
But, I am not sure if I have used the correct command. Is the above command correct?

Then, I tried the following commads to generate main.so ,

```
g++ -shared -o main.so main.o -L. -lCmodel
g++ -shared -o main.so main.o -L. -lCmodel -lAmodel -lBmodel
g++ -shared -o main.so main.o -L. -lCmodel -lAmodel.4 -lBmodel.11
g++ -shared -o main.so main.o -L. -lCmodel -lAmodel.so.4 -lBmodel.so.11
```

Which one of the above commands is correct?
Please help

Comment: I have used `gcc -x c++ -I. -L.  -lCmodel -Wl,-rpath,. -o main.o main.c` to compile and execute main.c file

Comment: This is apparently not compiled as C, but C++, a different language. Use the correct tags. And why do you use the `.c` file extension for C++ code? Use `.cpp` or `.c++` and leave the rest to the gcc frontend.

Comment: This is a c file not a cpp file. So, I used .c as extension.

Comment: You complied as C++ which is a different language! Your edit changed the question, leaving the answer without context. This is not allowed; rolled back. Read  [ask] and take the [tour]. And read the tag wikis and learn the langugages to see the differences.

Comment: Hi Olaf, I tried to mention that I have changed the qn according to my previous comment. But II couldn't do that because of 5 mins restriction.

Comment: Compiling a c file with c++ compiler is working, my question is about creation of ".so" file

Comment: `gcc -x c++ -fPIC main.c -o main.o -c -I.` and 
 
`g++ -shared -o main.so main.o -L. -lCmodel` worked. Thanks @Olaf @dbush

Comment: You can use any extension you want. It is just not C, but C++! Identical syntax does not imply identical semantics! If someone told you C is a subset of C++, he is never wrote much more than "Hello World" in at least one of those languages.

Answer (score 0):

The file containing your `main` function should not be a shared library.  It is the entry point for an application, so it should be linked as an executable.

```
gcc -x c++ -I. -L. -o main main.c -lCmodel
```

Comment: I use the file containing the `main` function in a SystemVerilog Testbech as a model. It needs a ".so" file and communicates via **DPI**.